# How to parse GML in C# or JavaScript for use with Unity

Tags: javascript, c#, parsing, unity-game-engine, gml

I want to parse GML and use the data in Unity.
This is my C# code for parsing the XML:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Manager_02 : MonoBehaviour 
{
  public GameObject text01;

  private void Start()
  {
    string path = @"C:unitySample.gml";

    XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(path);
    XNamespace gml = "http://www.opengis.net/gml";

    Text txt = GameObject.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
    //this is for unity

    var query = xd.Descendants(gml + "coord")
        .Select(e => new
        {
            X = (decimal)e.Element(gml + "X"),
            Y = (decimal)e.Element(gml + "Y")
        });

    foreach (var c in query)
    {
      txt.text = c.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

This works well when applied to this XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<schema xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema'
        xmlns:gml='http://www.opengis.net/gml'
        xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance'
        xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.opengis.net/gml/feature.xsd'>
  <gml:Polygon srsName='http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4283'>
    <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
      <gml:LinearRing>
        <gml:coord>
          <gml:X>152.035953</gml:X>
          <gml:Y>-28.2103190007845</gml:Y>
        </gml:coord>
      </gml:LinearRing>
    </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
  </gml:Polygon>
</schema>
```

However, when I use the XML below, it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<IndoorFeatures xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/indoorgml/1.0/core"
                xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" 
                xmlns:ns4="http://www.opengis.net/indoorgml/1.0/navigation" 
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                gml:id="IFs" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/indoorgml/1.0/core http://schemas.opengis.net/indoorgml/1.0/indoorgmlcore.xsd">
    <gml:name>IFs</gml:name>
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsDimension="3" srsName="EPSG::4326">
            <gml:lowerCorner>112.1168351477 48.8817891374 10.0</gml:lowerCorner>
            <gml:upperCorner>116.7830482115 88.0511182109 20.0</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <primalSpaceFeatures>
        <PrimalSpaceFeatures gml:id="PS2">
            <gml:name>PS2</gml:name>
            <gml:boundedBy xsi:nil="true"/>
            <cellSpaceMember>
                <CellSpace gml:id="C45">
                    <gml:description>Usage=Room</gml:description>
                    <gml:name>C45</gml:name>
                    <gml:boundedBy xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Geometry3D>
                        <gml:Solid gml:id="SOLID1">
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:Shell>
                                    <gml:surfaceMember>
                                        <gml:Polygon gml:id="POLY56">
                                            <gml:name>POLY56</gml:name>
                                            <gml:exterior>
                                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                                    <gml:pos>114.7255054432 56.357827476 10.0</gml:pos>
                                                 </gml:LinearRing>
                                            </gml:exterior>
                                        </gml:Polygon>
                                    </gml:surfaceMember>
                                </gml:Shell>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:Solid>
                    </Geometry3D>
                    <duality xlink:href="#R1"/>
                    <partialboundedBy xlink:href="#Door1"/>
                    <partialboundedBy xlink:href="#CB220"/>
                    <partialboundedBy xlink:href="#CB221"/>
                </CellSpace>
            </cellSpaceMember>
        </PrimalSpaceFeatures>
    </primalSpaceFeatures>
</IndoorFeatures>
```

I naturally prefer to use simple code like the following:

```
var query = xd.Descendants(gml + "LinearRing").Select(
    e => new
    {
        X = (decimal)e.Element(gml + "pos")
    }
);
```

How can I parse GML in C# (or JavaScript) in order to use unity?

Comment: I reformulated the title and the question, improved some grammar and code formatting as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this.  You have namespace issues :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication65
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement indoorFeatures = doc.Root;

            XNamespace xsGml= indoorFeatures.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("gml");
            XNamespace ns = indoorFeatures.GetDefaultNamespace();

            var results = doc.Elements(ns + "IndoorFeatures").Select(x => new {
                name = (string)x.Element(xsGml + "name"),
                lowerCorner = (string)x.Descendants(xsGml +  "lowerCorner").FirstOrDefault(),
                upperCorner = (string)x.Descendants(xsGml + "upperCorner").FirstOrDefault(),
                primalSpaceFeatures = x.Descendants(ns + "PrimalSpaceFeatures").Select(y => new {
                    name = (string)y.Element(xsGml + "name"),
                    cellSpace = (string)y.Descendants(ns + "CellSpace").FirstOrDefault().Attribute(xsGml + "id"),
                    description = (string)y.Descendants(xsGml + "description").FirstOrDefault(),
                    cellSpaceName = (string)y.Descendants(ns + "CellSpace").FirstOrDefault().Element(xsGml + "name")
                }).ToList()
            }).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }

}
```